# Nested angular material table

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm trying to create an imbric table using angular material table component, I'd like to have a parent table with a dynamic child table, i.e. have 5 or 6 tree levels. for this example please inject same data to datasource each time. I've done some research, there are other libraries with components that manage node arrays, but here I'm trying to do it with this material array.

thanks

**html**

```
<table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  @for (column of columnsToDisplay; track column) {
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  }
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expand">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef aria-label="row actions">&nbsp;</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      <button mat-icon-button aria-label="expand row" (click)="(expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element); $event.stopPropagation()">
        @if (expandedElement === element) {
          <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
        } @else {
          <mat-icon>keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
        }
      </button>
    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <!-- Expanded Content Column - The detail row is made up of this one column that spans across all columns -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplayWithExpand.length">
      <table mat-table
       [dataSource]="dataSource" multiTemplateDataRows
       class="mat-elevation-z8">
  @for (column of columnsToDisplay; track column) {
    <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column}}">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{column}} </th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column]}} </td>
    </ng-container>
  }

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplayWithExpand"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplayWithExpand" (click)="childRow(row)">
  </tr>
</table>

    </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplayWithExpand"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplayWithExpand;"
      class="example-element-row"
      [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"
      (click)="expandedElement = expandedElement === element ? null : element">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ['expandedDetail']" class="example-detail-row"></tr>
</table>
```

**ts**

```
@Component({
  animations: [
    trigger('detailExpand', [
      state('collapsed,void', style({height: '0px', minHeight: '0'})),
      state('expanded', style({height: '*'})),
      transition('expanded <=> collapsed', animate('225ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0.0, 0.2, 1)')),
    ]),
  ],
})
export class TableExpandableRowsExample {
  dataSource = ELEMENT_DATA;
  columnsToDisplay = ['name', 'weight', 'symbol', 'position'];
  columnsToDisplayWithExpand = [...this.columnsToDisplay, 'expand'];
  expandedElement: PeriodicElement | null;
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
  description: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {
    position: 1,
    name: 'Hydrogen',
    weight: 1.0079,
    symbol: 'H',
    description: `Hydrogen is a chemical element with symbol H and atomic number 1. With a standard
        atomic weight of 1.008, hydrogen is the lightest element on the periodic table.`,
  },
  {
    position: 2,
    name: 'Helium',
    weight: 4.0026,
    symbol: 'He',
    description: `Helium is a chemical element with symbol He and atomic number 2. It is a
        colorless, odorless, tasteless, non-toxic, inert, monatomic gas, the first in the noble gas
        group in the periodic table. Its boiling point is the lowest among all the elements.`,
  },
];
```

Comment: Require a working stackblitz with the issue replicated and the data you want to render at multiple levels. The data object provided is not a nested array of objects, so its confusing what actually is the problem!

Comment: the current list is not a nested list because I only call a flat list with the parent id I call another flat list not a nested list